# What is best practice for transferFrom out of these two ways

Tags: solidity, erc-20, transfer, require, transferfrom

I want to know which among these is best practice when dealing with transferFrom. that is when one should wrap it in require and when not to.

```
require(token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(0),token amount), "token transfer from sender failed");
```

or

```
token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(0), Amount);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check at the implementation of `transferFrom` (check here: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol#L158), there's no room for a returned value `false`.
It does not return any false value. It either works and returns `true`, or does not work and throws an error and reverts.

So, there's no need to add that line `require(token.transferFrom(msg.sender, addr, amount), "token transfer from sender failed");`.

With `token.transferFrom(msg.sender, addr, amount);` is enough.

If `token.transferFrom` call fails, it will revert with the reason the ERC20 library throws.

Answer (score 4):

Jeremy's answer is incorrect. While it's true that Openzeppelin's implementation does never return `false`, other implementations might do it.

According to the [EIP-20](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20), a token can return `false`, and it's the job of the caller to revert in case:

> Callers MUST handle `false` from `returns (bool success)`. Callers MUST NOT assume that false is never returned!

So using `token.transferFrom(msg.sender, addr, amount);` is NOT enough. The risk is that you're assuming the transfer was successful when actually it wasn't. Example of tokens that don't revert: ZRX, HT, WOO.

Also using `require(token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(0),token amount), "...");` isn't quite safe. There are indeed some common tokens that aren't ERC20-compliant and don't return `true` on success. USDT is an example.

To answer the question, both of the two methods have their pitfalls. The safest method is using this:

```
(bool success, bytes memory data) = address(token).call(abi.encodeWithSelector(token.transferFrom.selector, from, to, value));
require(success && (data.length == 0 || abi.decode(data, (bool))), 'token transfer from sender failed');
```

This is the one used by Openzeppelin's [SafeERC20 library](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol).