# How can we use safeTransferFrom function in a try/catch block?

Tags: solidity, try-catch

I'm trying to have a function that transfers some tokens, and if that transfer fails, stores the amount in a mapping.
Since we want to account for both revertion of the transfer call and the call returning false but not reverting, I wanted to use OpenZeppelin's SafeERC20 safeTransferFrom function, which reverts on any case except success. The code looks like this:

```
(pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
using SafeERC20 for IERC20;)

try token.safeTransferFrom(origin, beneficiary, amount) {
    emit ERC20TokensReleased(beneficiary, address(token), amount);            
} catch {
    // if transfer fails, store amount to unsentAmounts.
    unsentAmounts[beneficiary] += amount;
}
```

The problem is I'm getting the following compiler error:

```
Compiler run failed
error[2536]: TypeError: Try can only be used with external function calls and contract creation calls.
```

What am I missing here? safeTransferFrom is supposed to be an external call, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Gabriel said, `safeTransferFrom` is an internal function. You can use this trick to make an external call:

```
try this.attemptTransfer(token, origin, beneficiary, amount) {
    emit ERC20TokensReleased(beneficiary, address(token), amount);            
} catch {
    // if transfer fails, store amount to unsentAmounts.
    unsentAmounts[beneficiary] += amount;
}
```

And put this function with the transfer logic in the same contract:

```
function attemptTransfer(IERC20 token, address origin, address beneficiary, uint256 amount) external {
    require(msg.sender == address(this));  // this function should be called only by this contract
    token.safeTransferFrom(origin, beneficiary, amount);
}
```

There may be other solutions, but they require modifying the safeErc20 library, so this is simpler.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! It works straight out the box.  I ended up using the suggestion you made [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/136039/what-is-best-practice-for-transferfrom-out-of-these-two-ways/136077#136077) though, since making an external funcition onlySelf seems a bit hacky... Is there any functional difference I should be aware of? I mean, it's the same code as SafeERC20...

Comment: Yeah it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

The `safeTransferFrom` function is an internal one, as defined in the [SafeERC20 OpenZeppelin implementation](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol#L34), so it cannot be used with a try-catch block directly in your contract.

You can use `transferFrom` and check for the result. Something like this:

```
function transferTokens(address tokenAddress, address origin, address beneficiary, uint256 amount) public {
    IERC20 token = IERC20(tokenAddress);
    bool success = token.transferFrom(origin, beneficiary, amount);
    if (!success) {
        // if transfer fails, store amount to unsentAmounts.
        unsentAmounts[beneficiary] += amount;
    } else emit ERC20TokensReleased(beneficiary, address(token), amount);
}
```

Comment: Ahh, I understand, thanks! But this would still have the issue that a revert in transferFrom would throw the whole execution, right?

Comment: Well, while some implementations does never return `false`, but rather throws an error and reverts, other implementations might do it. I recommend you reading this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/136077/119701).

Comment: Thanks! I used 0xSanson's solution from the link you supplied. That should cover both cases